# jQuery trigger call to URL on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm trying to to trigger pregenerated URL to export CSV as follow:

```
// call API for CSV export
$( ".buttons-csv" ).click(function(e) {

    var csvURL = csvAPI(dlog);
    $.get( csvURL, function( data ) {
        alert( "Export was performed." );
    });
});
```

problem is that will not call created `csvURL` URL to download a file.

I have tried to get it done via

```
window.location.href = csvURL
```

but that wasn't work either.

Comment: And what is the url ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown It generated in `csvAPI` and looks like `http://domain/logs?startdate=2019-05-30&enddate=2019-05-30&filter=string&filter_status=test&_format=csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downloads don't occur when you use AJAX, only when the browser opens the URL normally in a window. Use `window.open()` to open a new window that performs the download, while not replacing the current window.

```
$( ".buttons-csv" ).click(function(e) {

    var csvURL = csvAPI(dlog);
    window.open(csvURL);
});
```